# Can I get back the reputation of a bounty if the author accepts my answer?

Tags: support, bounties

Recently, by mistake, I've set a bounty for a question that was asked by another account.
I've read a lot about bounty policies here, however, I don't understand my condition.

The question hasn't been asked by me. If I answer the question and the author of that question accepts my answer, what would happen to the bounty? Can I get it back this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is unfortunate for you, but this is what the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) says:

> #### How is a bounty awarded?
>
> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. **(You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)**

Whether the author of the question accepts your answer or not doesn't matter.

If you don't award the bounty after 7 days, there's a system in place for automatic bounty awarding, but according to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/295232) your own answers don't qualify for that either:

> - They were posted *after* the bounty was started, and
> - They have a score of at least 2 (at the time the automatic awarding takes place), and
> - They were not written by the bounty starter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for editing the question. Unfortunately, yes.

Answer (score 6):

> The question hasn't been asked by me. If I answer the question and the author of that question accepts my answer, what would happen to the bounty? Can I get it back this way?

Only indirectly. Once you clicked the button to offer the bounty, the "money" is deducted from your account and *gone for good*.

But, what you can do: write an excellent answer. Bounties attract viewers. Viewers often vote on helpful/high quality content. Of course, it *might* help to add a comment below your answer to express that mistake, to avoid the impression that the sole purpose of you putting up that bounty was to advertize *your own* answer content.

In other words: the only way to "get back" a bounty is by writing down upvote-worthy content. Depending on context, there is a realistic chance that the upvotes that come in "because bounty" will make up for the bounty itself. (most of the bounties I offered or earned on SO worked out that way)

Comment: This's a nice idea. I'll do it.